# How to include a directory of files with RST and Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to write documentation and want and have multiply files used by multiple toc trees. Previously I used an empty file with `.. include:: <isonum.txt>` however, this does not work for multiply files in a directory with sub directories. Another solution I have used was to use a relative file path to the index file I am linking to. However this messes up the sphinx nav tree. So my question is how to include a directory of files with RST and Sphinx?

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: You might want to have a look at [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67401478/14488888) since I needed something similar. Basically, generate (either manually or automatically) a single file (e.g. ``include.rst``) that contains one ``.. include:: `` directive per file. Then, you only need to include this only file in your source file.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done, unfortunately.

The [`toctree`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html) directive has a `glob` option, which you would use like so:

```
.. toctree::
   :glob:

   generated/*
```

But this option is not available in the [`include`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) directive.

Maybe start an issue for it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps indicate the start and end of the section where the files should go with a comment (`.. START_GLOB_INCLUDE` etc), and then have a build pre-process step that finds the files you want and rewrites that section of the master file.