# Include multiple RST files with Sphinx with directive .. include::

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In my Sphinx project, I want to have an include folder with multiple RST files that I can reuse in other projects. My source folder looks something like:

```
\source
    \include
         links.rst  # Here I have useful external links
         roles.rst  # Here I define custom roles
         subs.rst   # Here I definne common substitutions (replace directive)
    ... rest of my stuff
    conf.py
```

Basically, I want to be able to write a single `.. include::` in my source RST files that will account for all my files, i.e. the equivalent of `/include/*.rst`

I have come up with a neat solution that I post below since it might be useful to someone else. However, it would be nice to hear other alternatives, since my solution comes with a problem of infinite loop when using `sphinx-autobuild`.

**EDIT**
I circunvent the issue of infinite loop with `sphinx-autobuild` by passing the option `--re-ignore include.rst`

Answer (score 1):

My solution consists of modifying `conf.py` to include this small piece of code:

```
conf.py

import os

# Code to generate include.rst
files = os.listdir('include')

with open('include.rst', 'w') as file:
    for rst in files:
        file.write('.. include:: /include/' + rst + '\n')
```

This will create a new `include.rst` file in the root source directory, which will look as:

```
\source
    \include
         links.rst  # Here I have useful external links
         roles.rst  # Here I define custom roles
         subs.rst   # Here I definne common substitutions (replace directive)
    ... rest of my stuff
    conf.py
    include.rst
```

With the new file `include.rst` looking like:

```
.. include:: /include/links.rst
.. include:: /include/roles.rst
.. include:: /include/subs.rst
```

Finally, in my source files I only need to add on top of the file the line

```
.. include:: include.rst
```

to benefit from all my custom links, roles, and substitutions (or anything else you might want there).

PROBLEM:
My solution here presents a problem. Since I use `sphinx-autobuild` to automatically build the html output whenever a change is detected, an infinite loop is produced, since each time the execution of `conf.py` is creating the file `include.rst`. Any ideas on how to solve this?

UPDATE:
I have found the solution to the problem mentioned above, and which was pretty obvious, actually.
Now I execute `sphinx-autobuild` with the `--re-ignore` option as:

```
> sphinx-autobuild source build/html --re-ignore include.rst
```

and the loop stops happening.
Now, this is OK if I change the children rst files (i.e. roles, links, or subs) but if the very `include.rst` changes (e.g. a new children rst file was added) then I need to stop and re-run `sphinx-autobuild`.